# How to generate a random number for each page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using node.js and express, and I'd like to generate a random five-figure number in app.js and return it to the client.

I'd like to do this on the server rather than the client, because **I want to be certain that the number is different for every user who is currently connected**.

Here's my current (broken) code from app.js:

```
// My first attempt - a function to generate a random number.
// But this returns the same number to every client. 
function genRandNum() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
}
// Routes
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Hello world',
    random_id: genRandNum() // No good - not different for each user. 
  });
});
```

There are actually two problems:

1. How can I generate a number for each client?
2. How can I be *certain* the number is different for every client? Do I need to create a Redis store of currently open sessions and their numbers?

Thanks for helping out a beginner :)

Comment: You can't be certain with `Math.random()`, that's for sure. The chances of hitting the same number are 1 in 10^18, I think, but still... `:)`

Comment: Does it need to be random? If you incrementally assign numbers to users as they come and then in your implementation of selecting a user do that randomly you can avoid at least one of your problems.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Odds (in this instance) are 1:90000, because the OP is using 5 digit IDs.  Implies this is not an application intended for large #'s of users, and not intended for the ID to be secure or unquessable.  Richard, You might find this SO page of interest:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Comment: Obvious question regarding persisting this: Would storing this value in a cookie work?

Comment: It might be helpful if you stated the *purpose* of this number.

Comment: @JamesAndino - no, it doesn't need to be truly random. Incremental is fine, just as long as people don't end up with the same number.

Comment: salt the random number with the users IP address or a session variable of some sort; people behind the same firewall/router will have the same IP though.

Comment: @Richard The next good question is does each number have to be unique across all users or active ones!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me, with index.jade:

```
h1 #{random_id}
```

However, as written it generates a random # for each *page*, not just each client.  Some sort of backing data store would be needed to permanently guarantee each client has a unique #, but since you're only using 5-digits (90K possible IDs), you're clearly not concerned with this being unguessable.  And if you only care about this in the context of a single node process, why not just use an auto incrementing value?

```
var clientId = 1;
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Hello world',
    random_id: clientId++ 
  });
});
```

Comment: Good advice - don't overcomplicate things :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For unique random numbers, you can also take the help from your user .. he can enter some random key strokes and then you can modify them/add/subtract something and send at server